How to customise ominichannel communication panel in dynamics 365 customer service
I am trying to call the js function from an ominichannel communication panel by click ofa  button or anchor tag.
But I am not able to add a button on the communication panel.
Kindly assist me with how to add a custom button in the communication panel.
I am trying to add a button on the ominichannel communication panel.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
